# str.translate vs str.replace - When to use which one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

When and why to use the former instead of the latter and vice versa?

It is not entirely clear why some use the former and why some use the latter.

Comment: Here's an exercise that may convince you of the value of `str.translate`: using only .replace calls, replace all instances of "A" in a string with "B" and vice versa. Note that `"ABBA".replace("A", "B").replace("B", "A")` does not evaluate to "BAAB" as desired.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks but firstly your example is not clear at all (you better write a longer comment/answer) and secondly it is not that I am not convinced about str.translate but it is about understanding the differences of these two and when each one is better to be used.

Comment: I will be more explicit: No combination of .replace calls can possibly do the same thing that `s.translate(str.maketrans({"A":"B", "B":"A"}))` does. Even clever placeholder strategies like `s.replace("A", "_").replace("B", "A").replace("_", "B")` will fail to produce the correct output if `s` contains the placeholder character to begin with.

Comment: @Kevin if you want you can give me a specific answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56378872/replace-multiple-special-characters-str-translate-vs-str-replace.

Comment: Also @Kevin cool but I am still interesting to know the difference in the computational complexity of these two methods (for the same task at each time apparently).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They serve different purposes.

`translate` can only replace single characters with arbitrary strings, but a single call can perform multiple replacements. Its argument is a special table that maps single characters to arbitrary strings.

`replace` can only replace a single string, but that string can have arbitrary length.

```
>>> table = str.maketrans({'f': 'b', 'o': 'r'})
>>> table
{102: 'b', 111: 'r'}
>>> 'foo'.translate(table)
'brr'
>>> 'foo'.translate(str.maketrans({'fo': 'ff'}))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: string keys in translate table must be of length 1
>>> 'foo'.replace('fo', 'ff')
'ffo'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer (upvote). To start with, I assume that you talk about Python 3 (right?). Moreover, so in the case of multiple single characters is `translate` much more efficient than a loop with `replace`?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a matter of efficiency -- rather, a loop with multiple replace calls may produce the incorrect result. My comment on the question hints at this.

Comment: Also, in Python 2, you used `string.maketrans` to make the table, which *had* to a string of length 256, which specified the replacement character for each of the 256 8-bit characters. Python 3's `str.maketrans` is more flexible, allowing replacements of arbitrary Unicode code points.

Comment: So there are at least two questions: 1) How these two methods compare in cases where both can be applied (e.g. single characters substistution)?, 2) Are you sure that with translate() you cannot map 2-chars, 3-chars and you can only work single characters? I had the impression that you could do the former too.

Comment: `translate` operates on a character-by-character basis; `maketrans` won't create a mapping that that has multicharacter keys; if fact, the table it returns has integer keys, corresponding to the return value of `ord`. `translate` itself appears to simply ignore keys that aren't integers.

Comment: Ok (your answer apparently is a answer to my second question)

Comment: By the way, char-by-char but still this means I think that you pass a 2-char to translate to another 2-char (but char-by-char). So my point is that at least the example that you gave above with .replace you you also do this with translate() I think.